# Need help in dealing with class/instance: My class is "not callable"

Tags: python

```
class Credit():
    def __init__(self, name, howmany, a,b,c):
        self.name=name
        self.howmany=howmany
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
    def credit_add(self,name,homwmany,a,b,c):
        add=(a+b+c)/float(homwmany)
        if add==4.5:
            print("당신의 학점은 add입니다."+"학교의 자랑")
        if 4.0<=add<4.5:
            print("당신의 학점은 add입니다."+"엘리트 집단")
        if 3.5<=add<4.0:
            print("당신의 학점은 add입니다."+"취업 마지노선")

        if add<3.5:
            print("당신의 학점은 add입니다."+"..")

Credit=Credit()
print(Credit("민영", 4, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0))
```

This is my code and I want to make a code using class/instance where I get scores from users and after doing some math, return it with some jokes (for instance, if your score is above 4.0, you are a hero to school)

but I get the error `Credit is not callable [21,7]`.

Comment: Don't do `Credit = Credit()` - this overwrites the name of the class `Credit`. Name the variable on the left something else - `credit` with a lowercase `c` would work, or `credit_instance`, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

From a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400613/im-a-newbie-to-python-and-i-am-desperate-for-your-help-in-dealing-with-class-i#comment108618971_61400613):

Don't do `Credit = Credit()` - this overwrites the name of the class `Credit`. Name the variable on the left something else - `credit` with a lowercase `c` would work, or `credit_instance`, or etc.